# Can laptop with bag be checked in at connection airport of Doha, after carrying the laptop inside cabin in the previous connecting flight

Tags: qatar-airways

I have a flight from India to US with transit at Doha (Qatar). Connection flights are on two different partner airlines.

I want to carry my laptop with me in cabin during the flight from India to Qatar. Since USA has banned laptop inside the cabin for flights from Qatar, is it possible for me to check in the laptop bag in Qatar? Will it be delivered at same time as the luggage which I already checked in India?

Comment: Hey, everyone read the question better, those are not duplicates at all. The question here is about moving the luggage from cabin to checked-in at the legs change.

Comment: @motoDrizzt IMO it does; look at the referenced new procedure of his airline, Qatar, which will allow it in cabin between India and Qatar and check it during the connection.